# cakephp json parse error

Tags: json, jquery, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have an ajax call that get's json returned but I am getting a parse error. It looks ok, not sure what is missing in the cakephp setup.

`{"member":{"Member":{"total_points":"18"}}}`

SyntaxError: invalid label

The error is on the first quotation

Cakephp 2.0

jQuery 1.9.1

jQuery code:

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://mydomian.com/loyalty/members/api/5749.json',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(resonse);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
        }
    });
});
```

I originaly had no file in views/members/json/api.ctp and I got the same error now I have this code in file.

```
<?php echo $callback; ?>(<?php echo json_encode($member) ?>);
```

MembersController.php

```
public function api($mem_id = null) {
    $options = array(
        'fields' => array('Member.total_points'),
        'conditions' => array('Member.member_no' => $mem_id),
        'recursive' => -1
    );
    $members = $this->Member->find('first', $options);
    $this->set(array(
        'member' => $members,
        '_serialize' => array('member')
    ));
}
```

I have put the json into http://jsonlint.com/ and that has come back ok

[image]

Comment: I don't see any inverted commas? Also are you using the `RequestHandler` component and have you set `Router::parseExtensions` properly so that the JSON View is actually used (which seems to be what you want as you are defining the `_serialize` view var, which would btw. causes your `.ctp` view file not to be used)?

Comment: Yes I have that setup in the routes  Router::mapResources('members'); Router::parseExtensions('xml', 'json'); and the RequestHandler in the controller the problem is the "

Comment: The quotes are fine, `JSON.parse('{"member":{"Member":{"total_points":"18"}}}');` triggers no error. What's the exact parser error you are receiving, also have you checked the raw output in your browsers network console and/or via its view page source functionality, to make sure there are no additional chars that aren't displayed in the browser window?

Comment: I have checked in the browser and viewed the code, no extra characters are added

Comment: Ah, I'm kinda blind... you've set `jsonp` as the data type in the AJAX request, but you are returning JSON. Do actually need to use JSONP, ie  a crossdomain reqeust?

Comment: Yes it is a cross domain

Answer (score 0):

A JSONP request, ie a crossdomain request requires a proper JSONP response, which is a function call with the JSON data passed to it:

```
functionName({"key":"value"});
```

The function name is defined by jQuery automatically by default, but can be overriden using the [`jsonpCallback` option](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). This name is passed as a parameter to the given URL, so the AJAX request will look something like this:

`http://mydomian.com/loyalty/members/api/5749.json?callback=FunctionName...`

btw, you can see the generated function name in the image you've added, in the error where it says `Error: jQuery... was not called`.

So you have to build a proper response using the function name passed in the request. This requiers using a view file, so you have to ditch the automatic serialization provided by the `JsonView`.

In your controller do not set the `_serialize` view var, but only the `member` var and the callback query value submitted by jQuery:

```
$this->set(array(
    'member' => $members,
    'callback' => $this->request->query['callback']
));
```

and then in your `.ctp` view file otuput the data so that it's in the format of a function call, using `$callback` as the function name:

```
<?php echo $callback; ?>(<?php echo json_encode($member) ?>);
```

The response will then look something like this:

`jQuerySomeRandomNumbersHere({"member":{"Member":{"total_points":"18"}}});`

Comment: Thanks for the help I really appreciate it. I have implemented what you have suggest by get the following error "NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://treacysgroup.com/loyalty/members/api/5749.json?callback=jQuery19102563835438492922_1379081505860&_=1379081505861" The full url is there.

Comment: {"code":500,"url":"\/loyalty\/members\/api\/5749.json","name":"Call to a member function serialize() on a non-object"}

Comment: So are you calling `serialize()` on an object anywhere in your view? Or maybe inside of a helper or element?

Comment: No but I have a feeling it is not using the views/members/json/api.ctp as it has never called that file. i have deleted that file anyway and still get the same error

Comment: Sorry I correct myself it does give an error if api.ctp is missing I have updated the code to include the file

Comment: According to the error message that is displayed when invoking the URL without `.json` extension, the same error is to be found on line 3 in `/loyalty/app/View/Members/api.ctp`. So what's in there? Is it the same as in `/Members/json/api.ctp`? I'm afraid I can't do much more for you from here, you'll have to do some more debugging on your own.

Comment: Yes the same code in both, I just that file in there in case it was not looking in the json folder. Thanks anyway for all the help :-)